# Can I re-create an error object with the original stack and stack frames?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, sentry, winston

I'm familiar with creating a [custom Error object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) in JavaScript like this.

```
class CustomError extends Error {
  constructor(args) {
    super(...args);
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, CustomError);
  }
}
```

But given an exception/error that has already been thrown elsewhere I want to create a new error object that is a clone/copy of the original including the stack.

My context is that I'm using a log reporter, e.g. [Winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston), to capture events and I would like to post error messages to Sentry. Sentry provides a way to [capture exceptions](https://docs.sentry.io/error-reporting/capturing/?platform=node) like this -

```
try {
    aFunctionThatMightFail();
} catch (err) {
    Sentry.captureException(err);
}
```

The problem though is that Sentry assumes that where the error is captured is where the error was thrown.

One of the benefits of Sentry is that it can report the line numbers of where the error occurred in an app but because I'm aggregating the logs the stack frame from the original error has been lost. I can save additional meta-data which I can send to Sentry but it still highlights the line with `Sentry.captureException` as the origin of the error and the stack frames from calling Winston.

[image]

Comment: What is `Error.captureStackTrace` ? This really sounds like an XY problem

Comment: @JonasWilms `Error.captureStackTrace` is from the MDN docs I linked to. I was trying to avoid it being an XY problem description.

Comment: `The global Error object contains no methods of its own` ... the docs you linked

Comment: @JonasWilms there is a code example near the bottom of the page. I was also unaware of `captureStackTrace` - its not part of the standard spec https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#Custom_Error_Types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sentry SDK assembles a JSON payload from the `Error` object you pass to `captureException`. I think you'll just want to assemble that payload directly and send it using `captureEvent`. See https://docs.sentry.io/development/sdk-dev/attributes/ for more information.